# Adding a logo to a bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've got a template I'm trying to edit and i've tried every posted solution i've found, specifically this:https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq but everytime it causes a format error.

My logo is 3000x700, transparent background...it has rasterized font so i was just trying to fit it, but if need be, i could put the logo in with html font beside it. I just can't figure out how to get it to fit into the default navbar. The closest I've been able to get is the logo in the right region, but it blows the navbar's size up. This is the default code:

```
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#"><i class="icon-rocket"></i> Landlr</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#row1">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row2">Project</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row3">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row4">Specifications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row5">Pricing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row6">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#row7">Get Started</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .navbar -->
    </header>
```

On the included example i tried, it actually removed the navbar...other examples wouldn't resize the logo despite my css matching. Help appreciated.

Comment: `3000x700` is unnecessary big, imo.

Comment: The width is to include business title. I can remove that without issue if I can include the font in the HTML. The height is just the logo png as it is.